# Perl: Pushing a 1d array into a 3d sub-array

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, push, arrays

I am trying to push/unshift a 1D array in a 2D array which is a sub-array of a 3D array. You can check a example code in http://codepad.org/5s8Og64k  to make this more clear, I copy it also here:

```
use Data::Dumper;

# @arr_3d ;
$arr_3d[0][0][0] = 1;
$arr_3d[0][1][0] = 2;
$arr_3d[0][0][1] = 4;
$arr_3d[0][1][1] = 3;
# @arr_1d ;
$arr_1d[1] = "new1";
$arr_1d[0] = "new0"; 

print Dumper(\@arr_3d);
unshift @{$arr_3d[0]},\@arr_1d;
print Dumper(\@arr_3d);
```

In other words, if we define the 3D array's dimensions x-y-z and consider x constant then we get a "2D" array . I want to push a 1D array into this 2D "sub-array" of the original 3D array.

The example code actually does that, **BUT** when I try applying it to my main script, the dumper dumps "**$VAR1->[0][0]**"   in the place of all the previously pushed-in data, and only dumps the data from the last pushed-in 1D array.

Any idea what is could be causing that or of a more effective way to do the push I describe?

*Extra info:*
The actual data structure is created within a loop, something like:

```
unshift @{$arr_3d[$index]},\@arr_1d;
print @arr_1d;  # This prints successfully the 1D array
```

where "@arr_1d" is created be simply assigning individual elements:

```
$arr_1d[0]='a';   $arr_1d[1]='b';    # etc, etc..
```

Thanks for your time,
Giorgos

Comment: Well, how are you building your actual data structure? Does it have some loops?

Comment: I added info for the actual data structure creation at the end of the post. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array can't contain arrays. That's why we place references to arrays in arrays instead.

```
unshift @a, \@arr_1d;
            ^
            |
```

In your "main script", you are putting two references to the same array

```
my @arr_1d;
for (...) {
   ...
   unshift @a, \@arr_1d;
}
```

This is normally solved by properly scoping the `my` variable so it gets executed twice and thus create two variables.

```
for (...) {
   my @arr_1d;
   ...
   unshift @a, \@arr_1d;
}
```

The other alternative is to use `[]` to creates an anonymous array when needed. (`[ ... ]` is similar to `do { my @anon = ( ... ); \@anon }`.)

```
my @arr_1d;
for (...) {
   ...
   unshift @a, [ @arr_1d ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for both solving my problem and teaching me something new. Truly kind of you!